# Make os.walk/os.stat ignore permission denied?

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, exception, os.walk

I have made the below Python 2.4 script that scans the files on a number of LINUX disks and returns their path and stats from os.stat in human readable format.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from datetime import datetime as dt
import os
import grp
import pwd

locations = ["/disk1", "/disk2", "/disk3", "/disk4", "/disk5", "/disk6"]

for item in locations:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(item):
        for fn in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, fn)
            stats = os.lstat(path)
            size = str(stats.st_size)
            user = pwd.getpwuid(stats.st_uid)[0]
            group = grp.getgrgid(stats.st_gid)[0]
            laccess = dt.fromtimestamp(stats.st_atime).strftime("%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S")
            lmod = dt.fromtimestamp(stats.st_mtime).strftime("%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S")
            c = ","
            t1 = ["0,", path, c, size, c, user, c, group, c, laccess, c, lmod,"\n"]
            outfile = open("/data/promigrate/DiskDashboard/Temp/filescan.csv", "at")
            outfile.write("".join(t1))
            outfile.close()
```

However I have discovered that I do not have access to some of the files on the system.

I get the below error:

```
abc12bmm -34> python files_scan.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "files_scan.py", line 24, in ?
        stats = os.lstat(path)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/disk1/file5'
```

Is it possible to handle the error in such a way that the process skips the permission denied error and continues to the next file?

I have been playing around with exceptions etc but no joy, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Justin

Comment: Try-except should work in here. Please show what have you tried and how it did fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the os.lstat not having permissions to run on the file, I had been using the try-except in the wrong place. To handle the error the try and except should be added as below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from datetime import datetime as dt
import os
import grp
import pwd

locations = ["/disk1", "/disk2", "/disk3", "/disk4", "/disk5", "/disk6"]

for item in locations:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(item):
        for fn in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, fn)
            try:
                stats = os.lstat(path)
                size = str(stats.st_size)
                user = pwd.getpwuid(stats.st_uid)[0]
                group = grp.getgrgid(stats.st_gid)[0]
                laccess = dt.fromtimestamp(stats.st_atime).strftime("%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S")
                lmod = dt.fromtimestamp(stats.st_mtime).strftime("%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S")
                c = ","
                t1 = ["0,", path, c, size, c, user, c, group, c, laccess, c, lmod,"\n"]
                outfile = open("/data/promigrate/DiskDashboard/Temp/filescan.csv", "at")
                outfile.write("".join(t1))
                outfile.close()
            except OSError:
                pass
```

This now handles the error and continues running.

Thanks for all your help!